# Unable to delete list item in react. Error shows: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make simple todo app.In this i want  delete item from list by onClick function. The button onClick returns function named remove(i) which deletes the item in list. But I'm getting error as mentioned above.
The code is as follows:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      todo:[]
    };
  };

  entertodo(keypress){
    var todo=this.refs.newtodo.value;
    if( keypress.charCode == 13 )
    {
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo.concat(todo)
      });
      this.refs.newtodo.value=null;
    };
  };
  todo(data,i){
    return (
      <li key={data.id} index={i}>
      <input type="checkbox"className="option-input checkbox"/>
      <div  className="item">
      {data}
      <button onClick={this.remove.bind(this)}className="destroy"></button>
      </div>

      </li>
    );
  };
  remove(i){
    var todo=this.refs.newtodo.value;
    var deletetodo=this.state.todo.concat(todo)
    deletetodo.splice(i,1);
    this.setState({todo:deletetodo})
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      <div className="lines"></div>
      <div>
      <input type="text" ref= "newtodo" onKeyPress={this.entertodo.bind(this)}className="inputext"placeholder='todos'/>
      </div>
      <div className="app">

      <ul>
      {this.state.todo.map(this.todo.bind(this))}

      </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The same problem arises if i try to call a function for to strikeoff the list item upon click on checkbox. Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your `todo` and `remove` function and also need to `splice your todo` array correctly.  As your `ref new` is not defined and unique, you cannot access the value so just splice the array by index

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      todo:[]
    };
  };

  entertodo(keypress){
    var todo=this.refs.newtodo.value;
    if( keypress.charCode == 13 )
    {
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo.concat(todo)
      });
      this.refs.newtodo.value=null;
    };
  };
  todo = (data,i) => {
    return (
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox"className="option-input checkbox"/>
      <div key={data.id} className="item">
      {data}
      <button onClick={this.remove.bind(this, i)}className="destroy">Delete</button>
      </div>

      </li>
    );
  };
  remove = (i) =>{
    var deletetodo = {...this.state.todo};
    this.state.todo.splice(i,1);
    this.setState({todo:this.state.todo})
  }; 


  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      <div className="lines"></div>
      <div>
      <input type="text" ref= "newtodo" onKeyPress={this.entertodo.bind(this)}className="inputext"placeholder='todos'/>
      </div>
      <div className="app">

      <ul>
      {this.state.todo.map(this.todo)}

      </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: can you please suggest how to strike off the text on checkbox

Comment: onchange of checkbox just add an style  textDecoration: line-through; after checking whether the checkbox is checked.

Comment: I am facing same problem with error textDecoration undefined. I used bind but still not able to debug

Comment: Can you ask another question can send me the link for that I will work on it

Comment: i posted a new question